# Can't find PHP MySQL insert syntax error

Tags: php, mysql

**I will do a sanitize and escape as soon as I get this to work properly**.

Database connection and selection are verified working with a select query at this point. Weird thing is, if I take this insert query and run it straight from a mysql command prompt, it inserts just fine.

subscibers table has 3 columns not allowing NULL in either column:

```
 Server version:         5.5.11 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
    +--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field  | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | id     | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | email  | varchar(45) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
    | active | tinyint(4)  | YES  |     | 1       |                |
    +--------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Code in php:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `subscribers`(`id`,`email`) VALUES(default,'ggg@nothing.com')";
print $query;    
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

printed query result for insert:

```
INSERT INTO `subscribers`(`id`,`email`) VALUES(default,'ggg@nothing.com')
```

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''ggg@nothing.com')' at line 1

EDIT: I am sure that there is no other email in there identical for uniqueness. Looking at the table list of emails, and none with that garbage in there.

Comment: What version of MySQL? And can you paste your exact `CREATE TABLE` code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

don't include id in your insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO `subscribers` (`email`) VALUES ('ggg@nothing.com');
```

OR set `id` to `NULL`

```
INSERT INTO `subscribers` (`id`,`email`) VALUES (NULL,'ggg@nothing.com');
```

Comment: No change. Same syntax error. From previous experience, putting default in a auto increment worked just fine. But neither default, NULL, nor excluding is fixing it.

Comment: It works for MySQL, other databases..I'm not sure. That's par for the course for MySQL though.

Comment: Right, and I am on mysql database. Weird thing like is mentioned, if i copied and pasted that output from php into a mysql prompt, it inserts just fine. no idea what the problem is.

Comment: NSERT INTO `subscribers`(`email`) VALUES('ggg@nothing.com')You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''ggg@nothing.com')' at line 1

Comment: Beats me, maybe need to do a server reboot here to see if it will clear up garbage. *Shrugs*

Comment: It's probably a blank character in your query.

Comment: I've pasted the exact output from php before calling mysq_query and didn't notice any blanks. Care to point it if you spot it?

Comment: just to make sure...you do have a space after 'values' right? this has got me stumped...i cant think of any valid reason for the query not to work.

Comment: doesn't change a thing with or without a space after values either. I gave up on this and restarted a new DB. Might have something to do with the darn latin1 table and database. started fresh with a UTF-8 general ci and works great now. Why? No idea.

Comment: frustrating. for sure :\ Sorry we couldn't 'find the problem :|  UTF8 is better anyway. maybe mysql was trying to tell you something (:

Comment: No problems. Thanks anyway. Much appreciated for the time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to insert the id as it is auto_increment and inserted automatically.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO subscribers(email) VALUES('"ggg@nothing.com"')";  
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

use this. also it is recommended to use MySQLi instead of MySQL functions.
Happy coding!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need those special quotes around the column names or table name.  Try this

> INSERT INTO subscribers (email) VALUES ('ggg@nothing.com');

Comment: Backticks around column names and table names are perfectly fine - they might not be needed, but they won't be causing problems.